# How to copy snapshot from aws to gcp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

**How do i copy a snapshot from aws to gcp?**

> Google is providing a service to import the data from s3, provided the s3 url. As the snapshots are not visible in the s3, i am not able to transfer the snapshots to gcp

Comment: What is the "snapshot" you wish to copy? Do you mean an EBS Snapshot, RDS Snapshot, Redshift Snapshot, etc?

Comment: what i need is EBS snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible to export an EBS Snapshot** from Amazon S3.

An EBS Snapshot can only be **restored** to an EBS volume, or **copied** to another Region as a Snapshot.

If you wish to take the contents of an EBS volume to another service, you could [create an ISO image](http://www.howtogeek.com/228886/how-to-create-iso-files-from-discs-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) of the volume, transfer it to another service and then **mount it** or convert it into a disk volume.